# html body extends after make element a negative position

Tags: html, css, position, expand

Here is my site : [SITE](http://vaidila.vdu.lt/~if120073/#)

Resize window until responsive design appears, and push "right" button on the top. The right sidebar disappear and appear, but when disappear, the bar take a position of left: -300px, and you can scroll to the right. Why would this happen ? With the left sidebar all OK. P.S. scroll with the middle mouse button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `overflow-x:hidden;` to:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 650px)
.content {
```

Leaving the final rule thus:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 650px)
.content {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 100%;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```